# Change Gtk.Button image from embedded resource

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, xamarin

I've been trying to set a button's image from code in a GTK (Mono) application i'm building in Xamarin studio, but so far i've had no luck. I can't seem to get any of the methods that work for C#.Net to work in Mono.Netm and I have no idea where else to turn since I've searched the web for anything I could think of, and the only results I got were for C#.Net.

My question is simple, and I hope I've overlooked something and that the answer will be simple too:
What would be the way to set a Gtk.Button image from an embedded resource by code?

Things I've tried:
* Reflection
* ResourceManager
* Image.FromStream (Doesn't exist in Gtk.Image)
* Whatever I could think of...

Chances are I did something wrong along the line but if so I have no idea what, so please help me out, even if it's by pointing me in the right direction on google...

---

**EDIT:**

For some reason @Jester's solution didn't seem to work for me because if you change a button's image, and right after change it's label, the button will only display the label and remove the image. But that's a poblem for another thead.

Comment: For the record, it works for me even if I change the label directly after setting the image.

Comment: I assume that it has something to do with the way Xamarin studio generates the components in the visual editor, but I don't know for sure what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you managed to miss the [Image.LoadFromResource](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Image.LoadFromResource) method or the [associated constructor](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aGtk.Image.Image%28System.Reflection.Assembly,string%29) :)

That is you can simply do:

```
btn.Image = Image.LoadFromResource("name-of-resource");
```

---

**Update**: works fine for me with this sample code:

```
using Gtk;
using System;

public class ButtonApp  
{
        public static int Main (string[] args)
        {
                Application.Init ();
                Window win = new Window ("Button Tester");
                win.SetDefaultSize (200, 150);
                win.DeleteEvent += new DeleteEventHandler (Window_Delete);
                Button btn = new Button ("Click Me");
                btn.Image = Image.LoadFromResource("pic");
                win.Add (btn);
                win.ShowAll ();
                Application.Run ();
                return 0;
        }
        static void Window_Delete (object obj, DeleteEventArgs args)
        {
                Application.Quit ();
                args.RetVal = true;
        }
}
```

Compile using: `mcs -res:foo.png,pic -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 ButtonApp.cs`

Comment: This got me to the point where the app crashes when I use a wrong resource name, but nothing happens when I use the correct one. Would you know what's wrong?